# Finite calculus: Apply difference operator to generalized falling factorial $(ax+b)^{\underline m}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, factorial

The $m$th falling factorial power of $x$ is defined as

$x^{\underline m}:=x(x-1)...(x-m+1),$

and the difference operator as

$\Delta f(x) := f(x+1)-f(x).$

One fundamental statement in finite calculus is the identity

$\Delta x^{\underline m} = m x^{\underline {m-1}}.$

However, there is a more general version (to be found, e.g. [here](https://archive.org/details/calculusoffinite032268mbp), page 68, eq.(6)): Let $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, then

$\Delta (ax+b)^{\underline m}=am(ax+b)^{\underline {m-1}}.$

Unfortunately (to my understanding) the author gives no clear justification. Is there a simple way to derive this from the previously mentioned $(a,b)=(1,0)$-case. The shift $b$ seems to be trivial, but I have no idea how to understand $a\neq 1$.

**Edit:**

As @BrianM.Scott pointed out correctly, the statement is false. As a final remark I would like to provide the correct version of the statement, which is true, to solve the misunderstanding of the Book cited above.

Define the more general $m$th falling factorial power with step $s$ as

$x^{\underline {m,s}}:=x(x-s)(x-2s)...(x-(m-1)s),$

then

$\Delta (ax+b)^{\underline {m,a}} = am(ax+b)^{\underline {m-1,a}}.$

This can be easily proven by induction in $m$.

Comment: Hi! Does a somewhat similar relation hold for the finite difference one step back rather than forward since $m\Delta_{-1}(x)_m =m(x)_m$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not true in general:

$$\begin{align*}
\Delta(2x)^{\underline2}&=(2(x+1))^{\underline2}-(2x)^{\underline2}\\
&=(2x+2)(2x+1)-2x(2x-1)\\
&=(4x^2+6x+2)-(4x^2-2x)\\
&=8x+2\\
&\ne 8x\\
&=2\cdot2(2x)^{\underline 1}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you! I just realized that instead of $\sum (ax+b)(ax+b-1)...$ Boole considers sums like $\sum (ax+b)(a(x-1)+b)...$, and I was confused, as he also calls them falling factorial powers.

Comment: @flonk: You’re welcome! Yes, that would make a considerable difference.

Comment: btw, without affecting your statement, I think the last line should be $=4\cdot(2x)^{\underline 1}$.

Comment: @flonk: I wanted $2\cdot2$, actually, and must have done the arithmetic without noticing **and** written the second factor. Thanks!